# Why update method in controller didn't work if submitting form tag is uploadForm

Tags: grails

I created a very simple domain class called `Test` which have only one field: `name` and I ran `grails generate-all Test` to create controllers and views. The updating method in controller is:

```
@Transactional
def update(Test testInstance) {
    println("do you go inside?")

    if (testInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (testInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond testInstance.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    testInstance.save flush:true

    def uploadedFile = request.getFile('myFile')
    if (!uploadedFile.empty){
        println "Class: ${uploadedFile.class}"
        println "Name: ${uploadedFile.name}"
        println "OriginalFileName: ${uploadedFile.originalFilename}"
        println "Size: ${uploadedFile.size}"
        println "ContentType: ${uploadedFile.contentType}"
    }

    request.withFormat {
        multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'Test.label', default: 'Test'), testInstance.id])
            redirect testInstance
        }
        '*'{ respond testInstance, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

edit.gsp

```
<%@ page import="Test" %>
<g:uploadForm url="[resource:testInstance, action:'update']" method="PUT" >
    <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${testInstance?.version}" />
    <fieldset class="form">
            <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
            <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="update" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:uploadForm>
```

_form.gsp

```
<%@ page import="Test" %>
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: testInstance, field: 'name', 'error')} ">
    <label for="name">
            <g:message code="test.name.label" default="Name" />               
    </label>
    <g:textField name="name" value="${testInstance?.name}"/>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
</div>
```

The update method didn't work. Actually, Grails didn't call update method at all (didn't show the print).

Do you guys know why?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean `<g:uploadForm url="[controller:'test', action:'update']" method="PUT" >`? Assuming `TestController` is the name of the controller.

Comment: Yes, and `TestController` is the name of the controller.
---
edit.gsp was created by `grails generate-all Test`
---
only I did is changed g:form to g:uploadForm
---
when the form tag was g:form, everything worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help

I changed form HTML to

`<g:uploadForm action="update" method="POST" >`

and everything is working